# javascript Sencha touch not displaying data on device only in browser

Tags: javascript, android, extjs, sencha-touch

Sencha touch 2.4.1 not displaying data on device, but does in browser. Here is my code:

```
{
                    flex: 3,
                    xtype: 'container',
                    type: 'hbox',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    height: '400px',
                    align: 'center',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'dataview',
                        height: '400px',
                        store: myStore,
                        padding: 15,
                        itemTpl: "{foo}"

                    }]
```

"{Foo}" only displays in browser, but never does on my device. Everything else displays and works perfectly on both. When I debug the device, I can add a break point to the `store: myStore,` line I see that it contains all the correct information for "{foo}" but will not display on device. Help.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Store code:

```
var myStore = Ext.create('myApp.store.myStore');
var myStoreTwo = Ext.create('myApp.store.myStoreTwo');


Ext.application({
    name: 'myApp',

    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox',
        'myApp.store.amyStore',
        'myApp.store.myStoreTwo'
    ],

    views: [
            'Main',
            '...'
        ],

        models: [
                 '...',
                 '...',
                 '...'
             ],

        stores: [
                 'myApp.store.myStore',
                 'myStoreTwo',
                 '...'
             ],
```

I create variables of the stores because in my Main class I have to change some of the store's proxy settings then pass it into the other classes for use. And the only way I can get that to work is to create instances of them with vars.

Comment: Please show your `store` definition code.

Comment: Done. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, your data structure a bit different or corrupted. Try to put the following in your item template. It will show you the data that passed to the template:

```
itemTpl: "{[console.log(values)]} {foo}"
```

Comment: Nothing logged into the console. What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure while packaging the app through `sencha app build` command you have mentioned the required json/xml file in **app.json**, without which it will not bundle the data files during the packaging. I think that you are trying to get a data from a json/xml file using `proxy:{ type:'ajax'}`.

Moreover, when you are including the json/xml files in app.json, don't forget to refresh the sencha app by using `sencha app refresh` command in your application directory.

Comment: I think you might be right, however see my edited post with the new store code, and let me know if you think this is still the problem. thanks